# how to turn off rotating cube animation upon user switch?

Tags: macos, terminal, user-account, defaults, animation

How to turn off rotating cube animation upon user switch?

I apparently need to pad out this qwuestion, so i will add
that it makes me dizzy

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Running the following inside a terminal window (shell) worked for me.

```
defaults write -g userMenuExtraStyle 0
```